# Check next record exists or not

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do the stuff like Pagination in PHP, so i am taking the record or limit 0, 10
Here while taking the data with that limit i should know that 11th record exists or not so that i can reduce one function call to get and check the record is there or not before displaying. I am using PHP, MySQL.

Comment: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS it will return no of rows return ri8???

Comment: yes, it will return the total number of rows that matched the criteria specified in query. Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) out

Comment: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is slow use count instead

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Take 0,11 (then 10, 11; 20, 11, etc.) but display first 10. This way you will always know whether the next page exists (by checking whether 11th record exists).

Comment: I too had this idea, but i need to remove last record from the return result. that is waste know?

Comment: I assume you are iterating through the mysqli result with while loop as long as it has data. Add a variable $i = 1; and edit your while condition to `while(/*not end of results*/ && $i <= 10)`. Make sure you increment it too. Now, after the loop finishes, check if result still has one more row and act appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

With paging I would like to go to whatever page there is. So before displaying any data. I would query a COUNT on the database to know how many records are there. Then build your page navigation.

Or do you only want to show previous / next ? Instead of something like:

`Previous - 2 3 4 5 - Next`

So I would use

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) as `NumberOfRows` FROM `tablename`
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) just before the fields you want to select

eg/

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
```

After firing your query with limit, you can fire below mentioned query to get the total number of records

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```